# How to use Python Amazon Simple Product API to get price of a product

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I can't seem to get [this](https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-amazon-simple-product-api) library working. I got my access key, secret and associate tag. And I am following exact same thing as explained in the `README`, however I am getting `(None, None)` instead of price and currency. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Is it because I signed up on amazon.in?

```
>>> from amazon.api import AmazonAPI
>>> amazon = AmazonAPI(AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY, AMAZON_SECRET_KEY, AMAZON_ASSOC_TAG)
>>> product = amazon.lookup(ItemId='B0051QVF7A')
>>> product.title
'Kindle, Wi-Fi, 6" E Ink Display - for international shipment'
>>> product.price_and_currency
(None, None)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was happening because the product I mentioned in the example was no longer available hence it was showing price as `None`

```
 >>> from amazon.api import AmazonAPI
 >>> amazon = AmazonAPI(AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY, AMAZON_SECRET_KEY, AMAZON_ASSOC_TAG)
 >>> product = amazon.lookup(ItemId='B00EOE0WKQ')
 >>> product.title
 'Amazon Fire Phone, 32GB (AT&T)'
 >>> product.price_and_currency
 (199.0, 'USD')
 >>> product.ean
 '0848719035209'
 >>> product.large_image_url
 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51BrZzpkWrL.jpg'
```