# Error 400 with python-amazon-simple-product-api via pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, pythonanywhere

I've been at this for the better part of a day but have been coming up with the same Error 400 for quite some time. Basically, the application's goal is to parse a book's ISBN from the Amazon referral url and use it as the reference key to pull images from Amazon's Product Advertising API. The webpage is written in Python 3.4 and Django 1.8. I spent quite a while researching on here and settled for using python-amazon-simple-product-api since it would make parsing results from Amazon a little easier.

Answers like: [How to use Python Amazon Simple Product API to get price of a product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24573983/how-to-use-python-amazon-simple-product-api-to-get-price-of-a-product)

Make it seem pretty simple, but I haven't quite gotten it to lookup a product successfully yet. Here's a console printout of what my method usually does, with the correct ISBN already filled:

```
>>> from amazon.api import AmazonAPI
>>> access_key='amazon-access-key'
>>> secret ='amazon-secret-key'
>>> assoc ='amazon-associate-account-name'
>>> amazon = AmazonAPI(access_key, secret, assoc)
>>> product = amazon.lookup(ItemId='1632360705')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/tsuko/.virtualenvs/django17/lib/python3.4/site-packages/amazon/api.py", line 161, in lo
okup
    response = self.api.ItemLookup(ResponseGroup=ResponseGroup, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tsuko/.virtualenvs/django17/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bottlenose/api.py", line 242, i
n __call__
    {'api_url': api_url, 'cache_url': cache_url})
  File "/home/tsuko/.virtualenvs/django17/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bottlenose/api.py", line 203, i
n _call_api
    return urllib2.urlopen(api_request, timeout=self.Timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 153, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 461, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 571, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 499, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 433, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 579, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Now I guess I'm curious if this is some quirk with PythonAnywhere, or if I've missed a configuration setting in Django? As far as I can tell through AWS and the Amazon Associates page my keys are correct. I'm not too worried about parsing at this point, just getting the object. I've even tried bypassing the API and just using Bottlenose (which the API extends) but I get the same error 400 result.

I'm really new to Django and Amazon's API, any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Amazon is answering you with a 'Bad Request' error. Meaning, you likely are sending incorrect information. double check your keys etc...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You still haven't authorised your account for API access. To do so, you can go to https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/registration/pipeline.html

Comment: You were absolutely correct, thanks for helping spot this easy step! I apologize for the late approval.

Comment: Another issue that might cause the same error is when you have multiple AWS accounts and are using API keys for an account registered with a different email than the one you registered for the affiliate program.

Comment: I know it's been quite a while since the answer but another point might be that the API looks up for .com domain. So if you are looking in .co.uk or .de you have to specify the region first.